# How I can ping ip from flex?

Tags: apache-flex, ping, blackberry-playbook

I'm trying to create flex application for playbook that pings ip addresses. How do you ping an ip address using flex?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I ping from Flex - AIR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185635/how-do-i-ping-from-flex-air)